# iPhone App Data Access

Tags: iphone, safari, data-access

Is it possible to access the data belonging to the apps that ship with the iPhone? I know we can access the contacts information, but I am interested in being able to read/write/delete to the Notes App documents that a user makes or read/write/delete bookmarks from safari.  What applications have data that we can access? Can we access data from anything else besides the contacts list or is everything else sandboxed?  I am interested in working with the data stored by these apps: Contacts, Text, Photos, Maps, Stocks, Notes, Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing but the contacts and some higher-level interaction with the photos app.  You can save an image to the photos app, and can allow the user to choose an image from the photos app for use in your own app.

The new 3.0 OS lets you embed maps into your program as well.

As far as texts go, you can launch the SMS application, but you have no control over what the contents of the message will be.